# What implications does the KeRanger infection have for Mac OSX security?

Tags: certificates, malware, vulnerability, macos

Recently some hackers [replaced installers](http://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2016/03/new-os-x-ransomware-keranger-infected-transmission-bittorrent-client-installer/) for a popular torrent client with an infected version. According to paloaltonetworks, they have no idea how the hackers managed to do this (let's just assume the server was compromised) and that the infected app managed to make it past Apple's Gatekeeper protection because it was signed with a valid development certificate. Although the certificates were revoked and the ransomware was removed, the article did not address a primary concern:

Does this show a huge security flaw, in that a compromised server can easily distribute malicious binaries? How could Apple have prevented this from happening?

Comment: I think the question we really want to discuss is the second one. What could Apple do and why is it vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this show a huge security flaw, in that a compromised server can easily distribute malicious binaries? How could Apple have prevented this from happening?

Welcome to the internet where not everybody is friendly, same as in the world outside the internet.

Apple could not have prevented the compromise of the server because the server is not in control by apple. And as long as apple trusts developers to sign their own software it is not possible to prevent the execution by harmful but signed software. Apple limits at least the impact by revoking the certificate as soon as the problem is known. Apple might try to restrict software distribution to their own apple store only and heavily inspect each of the offered software. But this has associated costs which not everybody likes to pay and apart from that history shows that it is still possible to trick apple into distributing software which later turns out to be malicious.

Just compare this too real life where you trust some Mr.Mallory because your good friend Mr.Pear told you that this person is trustworthy. You would probably not call it "a huge security flaw" if it turns out that Mr.Mallory is a crook which tricked both you and Mr.Pear. Instead you would accept it as something which just happens from time to time because there is no such thing as full security.

Answer (score 1):

OSX allows the user to choose from 3 options which impact the strength of the OSX Gatekeeper

1. Allow installation of only apps from the Apple store
2. Allow only from Apple Store and identified developers
3. Anywhere

The default is 1, which would have protected the user in this case as the software had to be installed from a 3rd party web site. If you stick with the default, your less likely to get malware (but there are no guarantees, just lower risk).

When you select 2. Your saying I will trust the Apple store and other developers I trust. The trust for these 3rd party developers is based on their software being signed with a valid certificate. The problem here is that nobody ever bothers to verify that the certificate is not only valid, but it is the certificate used by the developers. In the current case, the malware was distributed with a valid certificate, but the certificate was one stolen from another developer. To some extent, it shows the weakness of the certificate system - if developers do not protect their certificates sufficiently, then you are at risk. However, I suspect that if someone was really diligent and actually looked at the certificate and verified it was for the developers who release the software, they would have found it was for some other developer and a red flag would be raised.

The 3rd option basically says your not interested in Apple's view of who can and cannot be trusted and you will make up your own mind and install what software you want.  You are also saying that you accept all the risk and it is all your responsibility.

Is all of this good enough? Possibly not. Is the Apple store 100% safe? No, there have been instances of malware in the store. Can there be a 100% safe solution - I don't think so and anything which claimed to be is either being dishonest or it would provide a system which was so locked down and inflexible, people would likely refuse to use it.

Can apple do better? Possibly, but we probably need to be careful what we wish for. Essentially, we have a play-off between freedom and security. All too often, people will emphasise freedom and flexibility and ignore security. They will choose option 3 to install that new free game and then blame Apple when their data is encrypted with Malware.

Most vendors, including Apple, can probably improve their security model  (actually, many vendors are really really bad - IoT, Modem and mobile phone vendors etc.) There are also some real problems with the current certificate model, but thats a hole other story. As far as vendors go, I think Apple is better than most and I don't believe the recent ransomeware is a sign that the Apple security model is broken - user on the other hand......

Answer (score 0):

The interesting part of this question is "how could Apple have prevented this from happening?"

As Steffen Ullrich has said, this is an issue of trust. Who do you trust? Apple? If so, you are trusting whoever Apple trusts. In this case, it is the developer and whoever controls the developer's certificate.

To open a more abstract discussion, let's consider all platforms that allow for updates.

**If your product has an update mechanism it is inherently vulnerable.**

Any software that can be updated has the potential to be updated with broken or vulnerable software. If you do not authenticate software updates, you are even more likely to get pwned. However, just authenticating does not ensure secure updates as we have seen.

The real discussion is the compromise between allowing (and preferring) update-able systems to close and mitigate vulnerabilities, and not allowing updates to avoid malware infections (while simultaneously restricting you from ever updating security patches).